# How do I average the contents in ArrayList?

Tags: java

This TestCode is supposed to create an stream of numbers in seconds.
Collect 10 samples, and average the time which each samples comes out.
I did try to use *if-else*, but the variable from *if* doesn't share with *else*.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.
I don't understand lambda just yet.

```
public class TestCode {

    private int eachTwoSec;

    // supposed to aList.add 10 items
    // average the time needed in between each aList.add (2 obviously)
    public void avgTimeTaken() {
        ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            aList.add(eachTwoSec);
        }
    }

    // return a number every two seconds (endless stream of samples)
    // samples 50,52,54,56,58,60,2,4,6,8,10
    public void twoSecTime() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Dummies.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ss");
        eachTwoSec = Integer.parseInt(ldt.format(dtf));
        System.out.println(eachTwoSec);
        twoSecTime();
    }

    public TestCode() {
        // construct
        avgTimeTaken();
        new Thread(this::twoSecTime).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // just a start point
        new TestCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using multiple threads, you *never* want to access the same variable unsynchronized. At the very least, you need to use a [synchronized block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html), and in your case it looks like you probably want a producer/consumer pattern with something like a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).

Comment: Your question title is misleading. When you run `avgTimeTaken()`, you just add `0`, ten times. The thread hasn't even started yet. Your question is not at all about how to average numbers in a list, it's about how to manage threads.

Comment: For starters: You are getting warnings about using a raw type on `ArrayList`, and you need to pay attention to them.

Comment: Never use `LocalDateTime` for tracking moments, specific points on the time line. I cannot imagine any scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do. Use `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` for such work.

Answer (score 1):

The literal answer to the question "How do I average the contents in ArrayList?" for a `List<Integer>` is:

```
list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).average();
```

Though I suspect that's not really what you need to know given the concurrency issues in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This may help to do what you want (or give you a place from which to proceed).

- I use a timer to take action every 2000 ms.  I prefer using the Swing timer and not messing around with `TimerTasks`.
- I don't just add 2 sec but grab the current `nanoSecond` time
- This introduces latency errors introduced by various parts of the code and
  of synchronicities.
- I add the microseconds to the `ArrayList`. These are in the form of delta from the most recent to the previously recorded value.
- and when count == 10 I stop the timer and invoke the averaging method.
- Most of the work is done on the EDT (normally a bad thing but okay for this exercise).  If that were a problem, another thread could be started to handle the load.
- I then use the original main thread to signal `wait` to leave the JVM. Imo, preferred over `System.exit(0);`

The gathered data and final average are all in microseconds.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TestCode {
    
    Timer timer;
    int delay = 2000; // milliseconds
    int count = 0;
    long last;
    
    ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    Object mainThread;
    
    public void avgTimeTaken() {
        
        double sum = 0;
        for (Integer secs : aList) {
            sum += secs;
        }
        System.out.println("Avg = " + sum / aList.size());
    }
    
    public void twoSecTime() {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        int delta = (int) (now / 1000 - last / 1000); // microseconds
        last = now;
        aList.add(delta);
        System.out.println(delta);
        count++;
        if (count == 10) {
            // stop the time
            timer.stop();
            // get the averages
            avgTimeTaken();
            // wake up the wait to exit the JVM
            // twoSecTime is run on the EDT via timer
            // so need to use mainThread
            synchronized (mainThread) {
                mainThread.notifyAll(); 
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCode().start();
    }
    
    public void start() {
        mainThread = this;
        timer = new Timer(2000, (ae) -> twoSecTime());
        last = System.nanoTime(); // initialize last
        timer.start();
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                wait(); // main thread waiting until all is done
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```